# Member.Activities always returns an empty list | discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to write a bot command to check the user's activities. However, it always returns an empty list.

```
@bot.command
async def status(ctx):
  await ctx.send(ctx.author.activities)
```

I've tried other stuff like getting the author's name and that works, but stuff like status and activities don't work.

Comment: What is your discord.py version?

Comment: @Nurqm Version: 1.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the new version of the discord.py(1.5.x), there're some changes about [`Intents`]. You need to define it to use some of the things like getting members, channels, activities. So you need to define `Intents` before you define the `bot = discord.Bot()`:

```py
import discord

intents = discord.Intents().all()
bot = discord.Bot(prefix='', intents=intents)
```

If you just want to enable to get the activities, you can do `intents = discord.Intents().presences` but I'd rather to enable all. For more information, you can look at the [API references](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents).